# Regex in Azure SCIM connector. Need to pull name from UPN

Tags: regex, azure-active-directory, scim

I'm new to regular expressions. I'm trying to write an expression that will take a UPN/email address and strip out the @domain.com. This works for a single domain:

Replace([userPrincipalName], "@.domain1.com", , , "", , )

It grabs first.last@domain1.com and returns first.last. The issue is I'm dealing with multiple domains and would like to use a wildcard or similar to take any UPN and remove @ and domain name. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When asking a Regex question its best to provide:
1. The language you're using - not all Regex implementations support all features.
2. Positive examples - i.e. joe@my.domain.com should strip @my.domain.com, bob.timmy@happy.org should strip out @happy.org
3. Negative examples - my.best.friend should remain unchanged.
4. Information on surrounding text - for example, is "joe@my.domain.com" the entire string?  Is it in a file full of other text you don't want to match?

Without this information answering folks have to guess.

That said, it looks to me like you want to match everything from the @ to the end of string, so something like @.+ should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Sorry, I will be more clear in future questions.  That's exactly what I'm trying to do.  Thank you.  Will attempt.